# Falcor Router set method

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

In my Router I have a set route like:

```
{
route: 'profile.["language"]',
async set(jsonGraph) {
  console.log(jsonGraph);
  // do async stuff w/database
  return {
          path: ['profile', 'language'],
          value: 'test'
        };
    }
}
```

The general idea with this route is to set the profile of a user. 
For testing purposes I just want to return the value 'test' on profile.language

The problem is I get a 500 internal server error with `model.setValue('profile.language', 'english').then(done => console.log(done))`

What's wrong with my route code? I can't find the problem...

ps: the `async set(jsonGraph)` is es7 await/async syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting a few hours on this, I found the solution:

In my server.js

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Express couldn't parse the incoming request, that's why I got a 500 internal server error.

Gotta love the fragility of javascript :)

Comment: I ran into the same thing with Falcor's call method.